# Sqlite: nested select with conditions

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am not very expert with SQLite, I searched but nothing came to help me.
The query is wrong, but the logic is what I would need:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_journal WHERE range_1 < 36 AND range_2 < 18 ),
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_journal WHERE range_1 > 36 AND range_1 < 100 AND range_2 > 18 AND range_2 < 100 ),
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_journal WHERE range_1 > 100 AND range_2 > 100 )
GROUP BY periodOfDay
```

I have the following table:

```
id, range_1, range_2, periodOfDay
```

periodOfDay is `0, 1, 2`

My aim is to get an array with just one query with

- total number of records
- total number of records with range_1 < 36 and range_2 < 18
- total number of records with 36 < range_1 < 100 and 18 < range_2 < 100
- total number of records with range_1 > 100 36 and range_2 > 100
  grouped by periodOfDay. It means I would like the total records of each condition for the corresponding periodOfDay.

Is there a way to realize such a thing with just one query without implementing it via code?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation -- that is, use `CASE` as an argument to the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT periodOfDay, COUNT(*),
       SUM(CASE WHEN range_1 < 36 AND range_2 < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN range_1 > 36 AND range_1 < 100 AND range_2 > 18 AND range_2 < 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN range_1 > 100 AND range_2 > 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM tb_journal
GROUP BY periodOfDay;
```

Comment: Is there a way - in case no records had no corresponds with one of possible cases of periodOfDay - write it anyway in the final results with 0 params?

Comment: @Soul . . . This answers the question that you asked.  You should ask another question.  You can also re-accept this answer if you feel that it answers *this* question.