# SQLite: query with indexes

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am working with the following query and it works perfectly:

```
SELECT periodOfDay, COUNT(*),
   SUM(CASE WHEN range_1 < 36 AND range_2 < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
   SUM(CASE WHEN range_1 > 36 AND range_1 < 100 AND range_2 > 18 AND range_2 < 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
   SUM(CASE WHEN range_1 > 100 AND range_2 > 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM tb_journal
GROUP BY periodOfDay;
```

periodOfDay can have the values `0, 1, 2` but in the database it could happen no records had no corresponds with one of possible cases of periodOfDay.
I would like write it anyway in the final results with 0 params.

Is it possible without acting java side?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

The first part of this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962541/sqlite-nested-select-with-conditions)

Comment: I don't understand what the problem/question is.  Can you show us some data which illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.periodOfDay, COUNT(j.periodOfDay),
       SUM(CASE WHEN j.range_1 < 36 AND j.range_2 < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN j.range_1 > 36 AND j.range_1 < 100 AND range_2 > 18 AND range_2 < 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN j.range_1 > 100 AND j.range_2 > 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM (SELECT 1 as periodOfDay UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as periodOfDay UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 as periodOfDay
     ) p LEFT JOIN
     tb_journal j
     ON p.periodOfDay = j.periodOfDay
GROUP BY p.periodOfDay;
```

Note that all the column names are qualified (i.e. have the table alias).  This is very good habit when the query has more than one table reference.

Comment: Thank you, it works (it adds a new row even though no records available) but the COUNT(*) for that row gives back 1 instead of 0 expected. So I edited your new query with 'COUNT(j.j.range_1) as "COUNT"'. It works. Is it correct?

Comment: @Soul . . . Basically.  `count(*)` doesn't do quite the right thing with the `left join`.